# React native remove scrollY listener with useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

```
const [scrollY] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
const [scrollYValue, setScrollYValue] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  scrollY.addListener(({ value }) => {
    setScrollYValue(value);
  });
  return scrollY.removeAllListeners();
}, [scrollY, scrollYValue, setScrollYValue]);
```

The goal is to instantiate an Animated.Value called `scrollY` and add a listener that will set the current scroll value into state. This scroll value `scrollYValue` is shared among components so they can do whatever they need to do based on how far the user has scrolled.

Things work fine if I remove the `return scrollY.removeAllListeners();` line, but I do actually want to remove the listener when this component unmounts.

Is this a case where my `useEffect` dependency array is incorrect? It seems to remove the listener right away and scrollY is just fixed at `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the return value in `useEffect` should be a function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  scrollY.addListener(({ value }) => {
    setScrollYValue(value);
  });
  return () => scrollY.removeAllListeners();
}, [scrollY, scrollYValue, setScrollYValue]);
```